# How to call a GET method from the same API in another GET method in fastapi

Tags: python, docker, api, python-requests

I have two get methods in fastapi inside Docker.

The first GET method obtains an URL if you put an ID in it.

The second GET method obtains and puts the ID you need in the first method.

But at the moment of executing the request inside the second method:

```
# Make internal API calls using requests
        response = requests.get(f"http://localhost:8000/api/canvas/{track_id}")
        response = response.json()
```

I get this error:

```
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | INFO:     172.28.0.1:57314 - "GET /api/taylorSwift HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     conn = connection.create_connection(
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     raise err
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     sock.connect(sa)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | 
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | 
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     httplib_response = self._make_request(
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 239, in request
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     self.send(msg)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 975, in send
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     self.connect()
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     conn = self._new_conn()
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     raise NewConnectionError(
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xffffa99bf2e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | 
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | 
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     resp = conn.urlopen(
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     retries = retries.increment(
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/canvas/4g2c7NoTWAOSYDy44l9nub (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xffffa99bf2e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | 
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | 
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 407, in run_asgi
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 271, in __call__
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 118, in __call__
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     raise exc
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 84, in __call__
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     raise exc
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     raise e
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 706, in __call__
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     response = await func(request)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 237, in app
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 165, in run_endpoint_function
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 41, in run_in_threadpool
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 31, in run_sync
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 937, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     return await future
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 867, in run
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     result = context.run(func, *args)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/code/app/./app.py", line 44, in get_taylor_swift
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     canvTay.credenciales()
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/code/app/./canvTay.py", line 55, in credenciales
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     response = requests.get(f"http://localhost:8000/api/canvas/{track_id}")
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 565, in send
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  |     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
spotify-canvas-downloader-master-web-1  | requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/canvas/4g2c7NoTWAOSYDy44l9nub (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xffffa99bf2e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

¿How can I pass this get methods?

As a side note, my code is working fine without docker. But the problem appears in docker only.

Comment: Docker containers require networking to be set up. Refer to the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) for steps.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Just the error message on its own isn't really enough to diagnose this.  If you really are making an HTTP call from a program to itself (not to another container) then `localhost` will be right without any particular networking setup, but are you sure the port number 8000 is correct?